# Login window freezes

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, freeze

I developed a login window because my program connects to a SSH server.

I open this window when starting the program. But I need to reopen it later for another server. The second time I open it, the login window freezes...

For information

Here is the LoginWindow code:

```
package com.maxbester.test;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import com.maxbester.test.Server;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class LoginWindow extends JFrame {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(LoginWindow.class);

    private Server _server;
    private Object _parent;

    private JPanel _panel;
    private JLabel _loginLabel;
    private JTextField _loginInput;
    private JLabel _passwordLabel;
    private JPasswordField _passwordInput;

    private JPanel _buttonPanel;
    private JButton _okButton;
    private JButton _cancelButton;

    public LoginWindow(Object parent, Server server) {
        _server = server;
        _parent = parent;
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        setTitle("Connection window");
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        _loginLabel = new JLabel("Login: ");
        _loginInput = new JTextField(System.getProperty("user.name"), 15);

        _passwordLabel = new JLabel("Password: ");

        _panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        // external padding
        c.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);
        _panel.add(_loginLabel,c);
        c.gridx = 1;
        _panel.add(_loginInput,c);
        c.gridy = 1;
        _panel.add(_passwordLabel,c);
        c.gridx = 0;
        _panel.add(getPasswordLabel(),c);

        add(_panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        _okButton = new JButton("Ok");
        _okButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                okActionPerformed();
            }
        });
        _cancelButton = new JButton("Cancel");
        _cancelButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        _buttonPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        _buttonPanel.add(_okButton);
        _buttonPanel.add(_cancelButton);
        add(_buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        pack();
    }

    /**
     * @return the _passwordInput
     */
    private JPasswordField getPasswordInput() {
        if (LOG.isTraceEnabled()) {
            LOG.trace("getPasswordInput()");
        }
        if (_passwordInput == null) {
            _passwordInput = new JPasswordField(15) {
                // Give the focus to this field
                public void addNotify() {
                    super.addNotify();
                    requestFocusInWindow();             
                }    
            };
            _passwordInput.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
                @Override public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {}
                @Override
                public void keyReleased(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                    if (keyEvent.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
                        if (LOG.isTraceEnabled()) {
                            LOG.trace("Click enter in password field");
                        }
                        okActionPerformed();
                    }
                }
                @Override public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {}
            });
        }
        return _passwordInput;
    }


    protected void okActionPerformed() {
        if (LOG.isTraceEnabled()) {
            LOG.trace("okActionPerformed()");
        }
        if (_server != null) {
            String login = _loginInput.getText();
            if (login != null && !login.isEmpty()) {
                _server.setLogin(login);
                char[] password = _passwordInput.getPassword();
                if (password != null && password.length > 0) {
                    _server.setPassword(new String(password));
                    setVisible(false);
                    synchronized (_parent) {
                        if (LOG.isTraceEnabled()) {
                            LOG.trace("syncronized with "+_parent);
                        }
                        _parent.notifyAll();
                    }
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(LoginWindow.this,"Please enter a password", "Password required", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);    
                }
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(LoginWindow.this,"Please enter your login", "Login required", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            }
        } else {
            LOG.error("Server is null");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(LoginWindow.this,"Server is null.", "An error has occured", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }
}
```

I store the parent class to notify it when the user has entered his login and password.

The Server class is very simple:

```
package com.maxbester.test;

public class Server {

    private String _url;
    private String _login = "root";
    private String _password = "";

    public Server(String url) {
        _url = url;
    }
    public Server(String url, String login, String password) {
        _url = url;
        if (login != null) {
            _login = login;
        }
        if (password != null) {
            _password = password;
        }
    }
    public String getUrl() {
        return _url;
    }
    public String getLogin() {
        return _login;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return _password;
    }
    public void setUrl(String url) {
        if (url != null) {
            _url = url;
        }
    }
    public void setLogin(String login) {
        _login = login;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        _password = password;
    }
    public boolean hasLogin() {
        return _login != null;
    }
    public boolean hasPassword() {
        return _password != null;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return _url;
    }
    /**
     * Test if the server has a login and a password.
     * @return Return true if the server has a login and a password, false otherwise.
     */
    public boolean hasConnectionId() {
        return _login != null && !_login.isEmpty() && _password != null && !_password.isEmpty();
    }
}
```

This window is launched by the Controller:

```
package com.maxbester.test;

public class Controller {

    public Controller() {
        Server server = new Server("myserver");
        login(server);
    }

    /**
     * <p>This method opens a login window and waits until a signal is receive from
     * that window. When the signal is received, closes the window.</p>
     * <p>The login window has to update the login and password of 'Server'.</p>
     * @param server
     */
    private synchronized void askLoginPassword(final Server server) {
        server.setLogin(null);
        server.setPassword(null);
        while (server.hasConnectionId() == false) {
            LoginWindow loginWindow = new LoginWindow(Controller.this, server);
            try {
                loginWindow.setVisible(true);
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                LOG.error("Thread exception", e);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(loginWindow, "Thread exception", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            } finally {
                loginWindow.dispose();
                loginWindow = null;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * <p>First of all, this method tests if the server is reachable.</p>
     * <p>If it is, the method opens a LoginWindow in order to ask the user ids.</p>
     * <p>When we have the information, the function checks if the
     * login and password are correct. If they are not, the function repeats the operation.</p>
     * @param server
     */
    private void login(Server server) {
        boolean badLogin = true;
        do {
            askLoginPassword(server);
            try {
                // test if password is OK, if it is not, throw exception

                badLogin = false;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                badLogin = true;
                LOG.error(e.getMessage(), e);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage(), "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        } while(badLogin);
    }
}
```

Comment: From where are you calling the `askLoginPassword` method?

Comment: From the Controller constructor. I am going to add it to the question. Sorry.

Comment: No worries. The thing is, in which thread is all this happening? If you are creating the `Controller` (and subsequently calling the `askLoginPassword` method) from a GUI event listener, you're probably blocking the event thread.

Comment: Basically, the Controller is created in the main. I guess I am blocking something somewhere but I cannot figure out where... It is strange it works at the first call of `login` but freezes at the second.

Comment: It's probably better to drop the threading and use a modal dialog instead d:

Comment: This is what I did before but it wanted to do it different. You have no idea where the problem could come from?

Comment: Typical case of blocking the EDT. Take a look at the [Swing concurrency tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

Comment: Do you think I should use a SwingWorker?

Answer (score 0):

it's a little unclear precisley whats happening (particular wrt threads) - but I think that you should probably go and look at the SwingWorker documentation to see how to handle long running tasks in swing,

It's hard to see which is the long running method (I assume this is commented out) - but that's the peice that probably needs to be kept seperate from the GUI thread.

Also, when are you expecting the login window to vanish? - after or before you have received a response from the server.

(edited in response to comments)

Comment: _the long running method [..] but that's the peice that probably needs to be invoked() later_ No, that would (and does) block the EDT. Long-running stuff must run on a background thread. InvokeLater is to pass a result back to the EDT.

Comment: I had a quick look at the SwingWorker but I think it is not what I need. My Controller class does a lot of stuff and is not HMI-oriented. I want to separate the GUI and the business (MVC pattern). For other HMI I implemented the Observer pattern. I guess I could also do it for the LoginWindow. But it sounded quite heavy for such a little window... What do you think?